# Javascript--Object Expected

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hello guys Im trying to change a select box based on a Text box next to it and I get object expected?

**JSP:**

```
NSN:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nsn" value=""/>
TAMCN:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="tamcn" name="tamcn" value=""  size="6" maxlength="5" onkeyup="javascript:tamcnSearchUpdated(this.value,'detSearchForm')" onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" autocomplete="off" />


<select id="tamcnList" name="tamcnList" onchange="javascript:this.form.tamcn.value = '';">
    <option value=""<c:if test="${empty form.tamcnList}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>&nbsp;</option>
    <c:forEach var="tamcn" items="${tamcns}"><option value="${tamcn.code}"<c:if test="${tamcn.code == form.tamcnList}"> selected="selected"</c:if>>${tamcn.code}</option></c:forEach>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function tamcnSearchUpdated(tamcn, formName){
    var tamcnUpper = tamcn.toUpperCase();
    document.forms[formName].elements.tamcn.value = tamcnUpper;

    var len = tamcn.length;
    if ( tamcnUpper.indexOf('*') >= 0 )
    {
        document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[0].selected = 'selected';
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options.length; i++)
    {
        if (document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[i].text.substr(0,len) == tamcnUpper)
        {
            document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[i].selected = 'selected';
            return;
        }
    }

    document.forms[formName].elements['tamcnList'].options[0].selected = 'selected';
}
```

I get object expected here:

```
onkeyup="javascript:tamcnSearchUpdated(this.value,'detSearchForm')"
```

this page is called filters.jsp and is an include on a master page where the form is set:

```
<form action="process.det_details" method="get" name="detSearchForm">       
<table class="data_table" width="100%">

<!--<jsp:include page="../../jsp/det/data_extract_favorites.jsp" flush="false"/> -->

<jsp:include page="../../jsp/det/data_extract_fields.jsp" flush="false"/>

<jsp:include page="../../jsp/det/data_extract_size.jsp" flush="false"/>

<jsp:include page="../../jsp/det/data_extract_filters.jsp" flush="false"/>

<jsp:include page="../../jsp/det/data_extract_results.jsp" flush="false"/>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: How are you rendering the `detSearchForm` form to the page?

Comment: I don't think you need the `javascript:` bit when defining the onkeyup handler.

Comment: @pete I just updated the question

Answer (score 1):

`onkeyup` (and other inline events) do ***NOT*** need `javascript:` in front of them. That is ***ONLY*** needed for `href` attributes on links (or `action` on forms). Remove that and you're good.

Comment: that didnt work...Im doing this in other places and it seems to work